# how can i transfer and remove single selected row from one grid view to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

i have two grid views when i check the check box it transfer multiple rows but it didn't transfer single checked row i tried code is:  i want to transfer and remove single selected and multiple selected rows.

gvDetails is selected row transfer gridview.

```
private void GetRemoveRows()
        {

            if (Session["GetRecords"] != null)
            DataTable  dtre = (DataTable)Session["GetRecords"];

            Session["GetRecords"] = dtre ;

            gvDetails.DataSource = dtre; 
            gvDetails.DataBind();

        }
```

can anyone help me out.

Comment: is this onclick event? in the onclick event get the selected rows GridViewItem and then add it to the other gridview.

Comment: i have no onclick event i have checkboxes on perticuler row when i check the checkbox they need to transfer from one grid view to another grid view  based on the user selection of single row or multiple rows by using the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

look at these code.

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<u>Selected Row Values: </u>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblValues" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

C# code:

Page Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!this.IsPostBack)
 {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Country") });
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
 }
}
```

And Selected Row Index..

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Accessing BoundField Column
 string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;

 //Accessing TemplateField Column controls
 string country = (GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;

 lblValues.Text = "<b>Name:</b> " + name + " <b>Country:</b> " + country;
}
```

Comment if you have any query.

Comment: i am transfering second gridview to first gridview but in this second gridview.in this first gridview bind from data base and second gridview has no items but i transferd frist gridview to second gridview i stored the second gridview data in session["GetRecords"]. what i need is i want to transfer selected row remove  selected row in second gridview and add it to first grid view.i transfer multiple selected rows but how can i transfer single selected row also can you please help me

Comment: Sorry, but i can't understand you. just let go everything, try to focus on selecting row and fetch data of that row. for that you need selectedindexchabged event when checkbox changed, now at back end you have that row, do any operation on it whatever you need, so simple, refer upper code, it will help you..